# How to access devices with IPV6 link local address from browser(like IE,firefox etc)?

Tags: server, ipv6, subnet, link-local

Both my device and the host through which i'm trying to access are in the same subnet.

**Scenario:**

I have a switch and a server in same subnet. I have to access switch using ipv6 link local address from the browser in my server.
Can anyone pls tell me the exact syntax??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A link local address can be valid on multiple links. If for example your system has both Ethernet and Wi-Fi those might be connected to different networks. Therefore you need to add a scope identifier to a link-local address. The syntax for that is to add % and the scope to the IPv6 address. The score is usually the name of the interface, for example `eth0` or `ens192` on Linux, or `13` on Windows. The value is different on each system, so you'll need to check what to use in your case.

That gives you for example `fe80::1111:2222%eth0`. The problem is that % has special meaning in URLs, so you need to escape it. The escape for `%` is `%25`.

The correct URL syntax is `http://[fe80::1111:2222%25eth0]/`. The official standard for this is [RFC 6874](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6874). Unfortunately many browsers don't follow the standard, so it might not work for you. In that case please file a bug report. There need to be more people complaining to get this fixed.

Answer (score 25):

To give an answer specific to browsers: for most common browsers, you can't.

There is a proposed standard format, as Sander Steffann pointed out, for specifying the interface for a URL, which is in RFC 6874.

The developers of both Chromium and Firefox, and seemingly most other browsers, have decided to intentionally not support this.  Firefox has actually had ipv6 link-local support intentionally removed.  Bug reports are closed as WONTFIX.  See [Chromium bug 70762](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70762), and [Firefox bug 700999](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700999).  Furthermore, [WHATWG also rejected implementation of RFC 6874](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=27234#c2).  This has been the case for years, so I doubt anything short of a patch or fork will result in link-local addresses working.  It appears that a number of people are quite set on not allowing link-local address support.

One workaround, however, is to use SSH forwarding.  For example,

```
ssh -L '8080:[FE80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%wlp4s0]:80' localhost
```

Comment: Alas: “[WONTFIX](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700999#c28)”

Comment: Recently the decision has changed to reopen this issue after all: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700999#c94

Answer (score 0):

For those who have no sshd server set up on their laptop and find it would be troublesome to set up one --- try finding port-forward scripts.

Here is a usable python script, without external dependencies.

https://gist.github.com/NeverBehave/357ca63941d4af4ee3f54920be3d1f3c

Answer (score 0):

There is a partial work around with Windows, which implements local link default scope.

e.g. If you enter just "http://[fe80::1]" (or whatever your target is) into a browser in Windows, provided the destination you want is on the default interface, then it will work. The specifications allow for a missing scope (or scope "%0") to be treated as a default, but it is implementation dependent.

This also requires the default to be the network you want, doesn't support alternative scopes (you still can't use "%x" in the URL), and doesn't work on Linux, etc.

Example: Accessing my local router (`http://[fe80::1]`) from Chrome on Windows:

[image: Screen shot of local link address working on Windows]