# Golang http server does not respond to ipv6 requests

Tags: ubuntu, go, ipv6

My server runs on Ubuntu.  I can ping my IPv6 address from external sites.
When I test my domain name in https://ipv6-test.com/validate.php I get checks for AAAA DNS record, IPv6 DNS server, and IPv6 web server.  The check for IPv6 server comes with a note: "cannot identify web server".

My server code:

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "net/http"
)

func main() {
  fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./html"))
  http.Handle("/", fs)
  err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

Like in this question [Golang IPv6 server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929114/golang-ipv6-server), I can load my web page by domain name, by ip address, but not by IPv6 address (http://[2607:f1c0:1801:1b4::1]).

When I run

```
sudo ss -6lp
```

I get

> Netid State   Recv-Q  Send-Q      Local Address:Port       Peer Address:Port
> tcp   LISTEN  0       128                     *:http                  *:*      users:(("go_webserver",pid=131015,fd=5))

```
me@localhost:~$ sudo netstat -an
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0    448 1.2.3.4:22          11.12.13.14:49978      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::10000                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: This might be related to IPv6 link-local address not supported by browsers. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46881540/5821408

Comment: I don't think this is the problem.  I changed the server to http.ListenAndServe("[2607:f1c0:1801:1b4::1]:80",  and tried to access the page by domain name, and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

does your client machine where you are trying to access the site from browser have ipv6 support?
you can check it with `ping6 google.com` ?

Comment: I think this could be it!  ping -6 ipv6.google.com and ping -6 google.com both fail.  ipv6 is enabled in networking in control panel and in firewall.  'ipconfig' shows Link-local IPv6 Address.  It could be that my problem is described here:  https://superuser.com/questions/435471/why-is-ipv6-ping-failing-to-access-google-com .  I didn't get it to work yet.

Comment: it seems like your ISP(internet service provider) doesn't have ipv6 enabled for your network. One way to get an global unicast ipv6 address is to use a free tunnel broker like https://tunnelbroker.net/. in this case, your machine should have a public ipv4 address for the tunnel broker to reach your machine.